# NSTimer get executed but does not calls the function

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nstimer

Im having a problem with a NSTimer and i really dont know why this is not working!

i got this

```
.h
NSTimer eventtimer;

.m
eventtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(CheckForAlarm) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The problem is that this timer gets executed but never calls that function..

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: I hope it is `NSTimer * eventtimer`. And how have you declared the method?

Comment: Yap otherwise it gives error "Conversion from 'NSTimer*' to non-scalar type 'NSTimer' requested".

Comment: Yes it is *eventtimer(typd it wrong here)

Comment: can you show your method's code as well?

Comment: don't use your function as -(void)CheckForAlarm:(NSTimer *)t{}

Comment: I cant show my method code sorry, because its getting JSON array's from an UPX server, but all it does is putting the JSON data into variables.. but the function doesnt even gets called so it cant do annything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .m direct use this without declare in NSTimer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:62 target:self selector:@selector(CheckForAlarm) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];//where required

-(void)CheckForAlarm
{
  //your logic
}
```

Comment: Still nothing.. and i need to declare a variable to it because it needs to stop when alarm sets off.

Comment: okej it works now.. the problem was that i was calling the function that the timer was in, in ViewDidLoad.. but it seems that you cant do that.. now its behind a temporarely button and it works, ty all for help!